# writer.writerow() doesn't write to the correct column

Tags: json, python-3.x, csv, boto3

I have three `DynamoDB` tables. Two tables have instance IDs that are part of an application and the other is a master table of all instances across all of my accounts and the tag metadata. I have two scans for the two tables to get the instance IDs and then query the master table for the tag metadata. However, when I try writing this to the `CSV` file, I want to have two separate header sections for each dynamo table's unique output. Once the first iteration is done, the second file write writes to the last row where the first iteration left off instead of starting over at the top in the second header section. Below is my code and an output example to make it clear.

`CODE:`

```
import boto3
import csv
import json 
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

dynamo = boto3.client('dynamodb')
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

# Required resource and client calls
all_instances_table = dynamodb.Table('Master')
missing_response = dynamo.scan(TableName='T1')
installed_response = dynamo.scan(TableName='T2')

# Creates CSV DictWriter object and fieldnames 
with open('file.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['Agent Not Installed', 'Not Installed Account', 'Not Installed Tags', 'Not Installed Environment', " ", 'Agent Installed', 'Installed Account', 'Installed Tags', 'Installed Environment']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

    # Find instances IDs from the missing table in the master table to pull tag metadata 
    for instances in missing_response['Items']:
        instance_missing = instances['missing_instances']['S']
        #print("Missing:" + instance_missing)
        query_missing = all_instances_table.query(KeyConditionExpression=Key('ID').eq(instance_missing))

        for item_missing in query_missing['Items']:
            missing_id = item_missing['ID']
            missing_account = item_missing['Account']
            missing_tags = item_missing['Tags']
            missing_env = item_missing['Environment']
            # Write the data to the CSV file
            writer.writerow({'Agent Not Installed': missing_id, 'Not Installed Account': missing_account, 'Not Installed Tags': missing_tags, 'Not Installed Environment': missing_env})

    # Find instances IDs from the installed table in the master table to pull tag metadata
    for instances in installed_response['Items']:
        instance_installed = instances['installed_instances']['S']
        #print("Installed:" + instance_installed)
        query_installed = all_instances_table.query(KeyConditionExpression=Key('ID').eq(instance_installed))

        for item_installed in query_installed['Items']:
            installed_id = item_installed['ID']
            print(installed_id)
            installed_account = item_installed['Account']
            installed_tags = item_installed['Tags']
            installed_env = item_installed['Environment']

            # Write the data to the CSV file 
            writer.writerow({'Agent Installed': installed_id, 'Installed Account': installed_account, 'Installed Tags': installed_tags, 'Installed Environment': installed_env})
```

`OUTPUT:`

This is what the columns/rows look like in the file.
    [image]

I need all of the output to be on the same line for each header section.

`DATA:`

Here is a sample of what both tables look like.

[image]
[image]

`SAMPLE OUTPUT:`

Here is what the `for` loops print out and appends to the lists.

Missing:

```
i-0xxxxxx 333333333 foo@bar.com int 
i-0yyyyyy 333333333 foo1@bar.com int
```

Installed:

```
i-0zzzzzz 44444444 foo2@bar.com int
i-0aaaaaa 44444444 foo3@bar.com int
```

Comment: You need to write the code to combine your data, then write each row once.  Each call to `writeRow()` will make a new row, it will not add additional columns to an existing row.

Comment: Do you mean "The **correct** column"? You may want to update your question with "correct" instead of "right", because columns are considered positionional: left, right, middle, etc.

Comment: @Smittles I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You want to collect related rows together into a single list to write on a single row, something like:

```
missing = [] # collection for missing_responses
installed = [] # collection for installed_responses

# Find instances IDs from the missing table in the master table to pull tag metadata 
for instances in missing_response['Items']:
    instance_missing = instances['missing_instances']['S']
    #print("Missing:" + instance_missing)
    query_missing = all_instances_table.query(KeyConditionExpression=Key('ID').eq(instance_missing))
    for item_missing in query_missing['Items']:
        missing_id = item_missing['ID']
        missing_account = item_missing['Account']
        missing_tags = item_missing['Tags']
        missing_env = item_missing['Environment']
        # Update first half of row with missing list
        missing.append(missing_id, missing_account, missing_tags, missing_env)

# Find instances IDs from the installed table in the master table to pull tag metadata
for instances in installed_response['Items']:
    instance_installed = instances['installed_instances']['S']
    #print("Installed:" + instance_installed)
    query_installed = all_instances_table.query(KeyConditionExpression=Key('ID').eq(instance_installed))

    for item_installed in query_installed['Items']:
        installed_id = item_installed['ID']
        print(installed_id)
        installed_account = item_installed['Account']
        installed_tags = item_installed['Tags']
        installed_env = item_installed['Environment']
        # update second half of row by updating installed list
        installed.append(installed_id, installed_account, installed_tags, installed_env)
# combine your two lists outside a loop
this_row = []
i = 0;
for m in missing:
    # iterate through the first half to concatenate with the second half
    this_row.append( m + installed[i] )
    i = i +1

# adding an empty column after the write operation, manually, is optional
# Write the data to the CSV file 
writer.writerow(this_row)
```

This will work if your installed and missing tables operate on a relatable field - like a timestamp or an account ID, something that you can ensure keeps the rows being concatenated in the same order. A data sample would be useful to really answer the question.

Comment: I have updated the question with screenshots of my tables and some output data of the `for` loops.

Comment: The method I recommend would work, but there seems to be a disconnect with why you'd want them on the same row. If it were me, I'd have another column, a boolean, called "Installed" which would have a Yes or a No (or True/False, or 1/0) as the field. Those could then be sorted. Your loop data doesn't have anything relatable - the accounts are different, the instances don't overlap, so there's (in my view) no reason they should be stored on the same row. Why are they on the same row?